# No South database module and then No Module named South

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am following this guide to setup Django: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/

I then added `south` to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
]
```

I then got the error:

```
There is no South database module 'south.db.sqlite'
```

I then typed `pip uninstall south`.

When I then type `python manage.py syncdb` I now get `ImportError: No module named south`

how do I fix this?

Comment: which version of Django (the guide is for Django 1.6)

Comment: South was the old style db-migration app to adjust db for changed models.  That functionality got folded into the core and is now accessed by things like **manage.py make migrations myapp**, **manage.py migrate myapp**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to follow an instruction date back to 02/09/2012? Django doc should provide you with much up to date info, unless you are stuck at django 1.6. In that case you shouldn't uninstall `South`, but install it and install django 1.6.

Comment: i couldn't find any other better instructions/tutorials for Django

Comment: As I said, django official doc is the best source to learn django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/